# Deleting a row from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table called "privatemessage" with a primary key field called "messageid."

I would like to have a PHP query that deletes any row from "privatemessage" where "messageid = $messageid."

What sort of query does this?

Thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM `privatemessage` WHERE `messageid` = $messageid
```

That's just the raw SQL query. Things like validating and escaping user input should certainly be considered.

For example, given `messageid` as an `AUTO_INCREMENT` integer primary key I'd simply run this in PHP (converting `$messageid` to an int using `intval()`):

```
mysql_query('DELETE FROM `privatemessage` WHERE `messageid` = ' . intval($messageid));
```

Comment: To expand slightly, [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_delete.asp) webpage has a small but useful example.

Comment: And you should use parameters, so that messageid of "1 or 1 == 1" will not delete all of your private messages (sql injection)

Comment: Indeed, if you are accepting input from the user for $messageid, be careful to avoid SQL injection. For example, the user might enter `5 OR 1==1` as their input. This then forms the query: `DELETE FROM 'privatemessage' WHERE 'messageid' = '5' OR 1 == 1`. Since 1==1 is always true, this would delete every row.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use a preprared statement, so you're on the safe side regarding SQL-injection...

```
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $database);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('could not connet to database.');
}
$statement = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM privatemessage WHERE messageid = ?");
$statement->bind_param("messageid", $messageid);
$statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "DELETE FROM `privatemessage` WHERE `messageid` = '$messageid'";
mysql_query($query);
```

But first of all, check that `$messageid` is a number (See [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)).

[Read more:](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqldelete.php) about MySQL delete